# How to read a CSV with Pandas and only read it into 1 column without a Sep or Delimiter

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas, read.csv

I have a txt file which formed of many email password combinations, the problem is it is full of symbols at the start middle or end. These can all be replaced using regex but my problem is reading the txt file and keeping all the data in 1 column. A Delimiter or Sep cannot be used as each line contain so many different symbols. Even the default ',' is not viable as come lines start with ',' so it would keep no data.

I already have a script which can find only the emails and remove noise using pandas and regex, but the initial read is my problem. Ive heard of using the python engine over the c engine but doing so causes some columns to show NaN and put the rest of the email pass combo in column 2 respectively.

```
with open(self.breach_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as breach_file:
            found_reader = pd.read_csv(breach_file, names=['Email'], dtype={'Email':str}, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, engine='c')
            found_reader = pd.DataFrame(found_reader)
            found_reader['Email'] = found_reader['Email'].replace(symbol_dictionary_colon, ':', regex=True).replace(symbol_dictionary_no_space, '', regex=True)
            found_reader = found_reader.str.replace('?', '', regex=True).str.strip()
            loaded_list = found_reader.str.replace(symbol_dictionary_first_char, '', regex=True)
        breach_file.close()
```

I just want the data to be read in 1 column no matter what symbol the line starts with. Any help?

P.S. I have tried using 2 columns and then if column 1 is `NaN` then create a new column with col 1 and 2 joined, but this is doesn't provide a feasible solution.

Comment: Could you provide some sample of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your file contains only the info of one column, or are there other infos as only the password?
How big is your file?

If it is not big, you can do something like:

```
with open(self.breach_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as breach_file:
    passwords= breach_file.readlines()

pd.DataFrame({'passwords': passwords})
```

If it is larger, you could read line by line and add the lines each at one time to your dataframe (but this might be slow). You could also try to use the read_fwf function, which expects fixed width files and thus doesn't look for field separaters. Apparently it does not require the file to contain lines of the same length. It would look like:

```
pd.read_fwf('fake_fixed.txt', widths= [100])
```

You only have to make sure, you use a width that is at min as large as the longest password.

Another possibilty is to use

```
pd.read_csv('fake_fixed.txt', sep='\n')
```

So you make sure the lines don't get split (assuming your lines are separated by newlines. This way you could even use a custom converter to parse out the email addresses (in case you really need only the info of one column), that might save some space.

Comment: To give you a feel for what I'm trying to achieve - Test.txt
/some@some.com:pas,s/[kdh]
  :some@some.co.uk;pa'ss,2,4,!/
;some@some.org:pass

So ill need all of them in 1 column but the delimiter or sep as most symbols will split a data line as 
col 1 - NaN
col 2 - rest of the email pass combo

So my problem is what do I do when this occurs to read the 2 columns as I line to extract just the email

Comment: Could you write an exact example of some lines of your file in your questions? I guess the auto formatting might have spoiled your example above. Are the line endings of your file clean? so that each line contains one email adress? Where are the funny characters that cause the problems? are there only before or only after the emails? or could they be on both sides? You are only interested in the email adresses, right? The fields seem always to be separated by ";" but ";" can also occur in the passwords, right?

Comment: If the funny characters (especially ; as a non-separator) are only on one of the sides, I think you could create a regex pattern that you apply after reading the file like described above.

Comment: Exact lines - 100k.
Yes all my lines are coming out from the mess I posted to some@some.com everything is removed either side and the password isn't needed too. My problem is when I read the txt file, if the starting char is a symbol of some sort, my delimiter chops it into two, NaN in col 1 as there is nothing before the symbol and the rest of the line in col2. But then on other occasions the : or ; is between the email and password, so in this instance Email is in col1 and password is in col2. In this scenario I want col 2 value from row 1, and col1 value from col2

Comment: Have you already tried the sep='\n' trick? This should prevent pandas from splitting the lines.

Comment: Is there any character which would break that? as its new line right?

Comment: I think only newline would terminate a field content.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

```
found_reader = pd.read_csv(breach_file, names=['Email'], dtype={'Email':str}, delimiter='\n', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, engine='c')
```

Delimiter or Sep both work.

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6925185/jottbe